# Is there a way to move a sprite across a multidimensional array board with specific interactions?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I was wondering if there is a way to create a board from an array list and and then move a sprite across that board with specific interactions.

This is an example of the array list that I created. Then, I draw the board out using the paint function. But the problem is that once I create the board and the keyboard inputs, I am not entirely sure how to move my sprite across this board with the specific interactions. The idea is that when the sprite lands on any number besides the number 3, it resets back to number 2. Is there a way to make this work?

Just to be clear, I have made the keyboard inputs, such as moving left when the left key is pressed and such. I am just stuck at making it reset when it doesn't into the correct tile on the board.

```java
private int[][] board = {
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 3, 3, 0, 3, 4, 1},
        {1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 1},
        {1, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}};
```

Comment: You don't mention whether you're using AWT, Swing, or JavaFX to paint.  My advice is to create a logical model from your board and sprite, and determine logically what happens when the sprite lands on various numbers.  Your GUI (view) should show what's happening in the logical model.  See the [model / view / controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I am using AWT to paint.And, ok thank you, I will try to do that.